# Logic Apps Access Office 365 resources with service account

Tags: office365, azure-logic-apps, ms-forms

We have created a MS Logic App that accesses O365 resources (namely MS Forms and sending an email).

We have the logic apps working, but we connect to MS Forms and Outlook through our own O365 account, but obviously for a production logic app we would want to use a service account. 
I can't seem to find any documentation for how to do this? Do we just create a new user account? What licensing does it need? What about MFA?
What are the best practices for doing this?

Comment: Also, on this MS page for the Forms connector, it says that Group forms will not show up in the dropdown. I also can't find any way to share the form without making it a group form. Does this mean I can only use the connector for Forms that I own? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/microsoftforms/

Comment: If that is the case, it seems rather useless to have a forms connector in logic apps, I can't even get data from forms my users create...???